# XSLT: How to 'filter' xml node with all its descendants by attribute condition?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML code with layer attribute in some nodes.
I want to copy all XML content, but without nodes(with all its descendants) 
that has layer greater than the layer parameter.

In below example, layer parameter get value 2, 
and I expect that all elements that have layer 3 attribute and its descendants, shouldn't be copied to the new XML.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="layer" select="2"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@layer">
        <xsl:if test="current() &lt;=  $layer">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input xml:**

```
<condition>
    <caseCond>Yes</caseCond>
    <inform layer="1">
        <para>layer 1 information</para>
    </inform>
    <procContent>
        <inform layer="2">
            <para>layer 2 information</para>
        </inform>
        <comment layer="2">
            <para>layer 2 information</para>
            <para layer="3">layer 3 information</para>
        </comment>
    </procContent>
    <endOfProc/>
</condition>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<condition>
    <caseCond>Yes</caseCond>
    <inform layer="1">
        <para>layer 1 information</para>
    </inform>
    <procContent>
        <inform layer="2">
            <para>layer 2 information</para>
        </inform>
        <comment layer="2">
            <para>layer 2 information</para>

        </comment>
    </procContent>
    <endOfProc/>
</condition>
```

**Current result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<condition>
   <caseCond>Yes</caseCond>
   <inform layer="1">
      <para>layer 1 information</para>
   </inform>
   <procContent>
      <inform>
         <para>layer 2 information</para>
      </inform>
      <comment>
         <para>layer 2 information</para>
         <para>layer 3 information</para>
      </comment>
   </procContent>
   <endOfProc/>
</condition>
```

SO, only **layer="1"** expression exists in **inform** tag, 
but **layer="2"** expression removed from all containing tags,

***And the most significant, the `<para layer="3">layer 3 information</para>` row still exists.***

while I want all tags with layer=3 attribute and its descendants will not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your @layerparm parameter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="layerparm" select="2"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@layer > number($layerparm)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @METAL, Thanks for your reply.
How can I convert the 3 you written as a hard-coded with a condition that will check if  the value of the layer attribute is greater than the value of the layer parameter?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can put a global variable in the pattern: ``match="*[number(@layer) > number($layer)]"`. Some XSLT 1.0 processors also allow this, although it's not allowed by the 1.0 specification. "contains()" is wrong here here, by the way.

Comment: @Michael Kay, I use an oxygene environment, with saxon-pe 9.8..0.12 processor. with xslt the contains allows. in xslt 2- not.  Anyway I need a solution that fits xslt 1 and doesn't include numbers in hard-coded. I would be happy to suggest a solution.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @MichaelKay, i updated the answer to use `<xsl:template match="*[@layer > number($layerparm)]"/>` instead

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ, I am use xslt 1, and got error:The match pattern in xsl:template may not contain references to variables. In addition, I would like to ask if the attribute is a large layer (absolutely) from the layer parameter, rather than a large in one. Thanks

Comment: @C.Mar, i changed param name to layerparm, because its confusing to your layer attribute

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ, I got an error: The match pattern in xsl:template may not contain references to variables. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199895/discussion-between-c-mar-and-).

Comment: I know lots of people are stuck with XSLT 1.0 but sorry, that's ancient technology and all my focus for nearly 20 years has been on helping and encouraging people to move forward to something more modern.

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
<xsl:template match="para[@layer]"/>
```

full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output  method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para[@layer]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not understand what the empty template that you have proposed is supposed to do ?! Also, I don't want to restrict the code to filtering a particular tag ('para',as you suggested), but to check every tag that contains a layer attribute.